# Wkhtmltopdf PDF printing fails intermittently on Heroku

Tags: heroku, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I am getting the following error frequently when using printing PDF on Heroku. The error happens intermittently and goes away when the delayed job server re-tries to print.

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

> MESSAGE    command failed (exitstatus=139): /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/wkhtmltopdf-heroku-2.12.4.0/bin/wkhtmltopdf-linux-amd64 --encoding UTF-8 --dpi 300 --margin-top 75.0 --margin-bottom 55.0 --header-html /app/tmp/LabReport-Mr.XYZ-14-02-2019\ header20190214-4-7ofe2a.html --footer-html /app/tmp/LabReport-Mr.XYZ-14-02-2019\ footer20190214-4-nf4kpo.html --disable-smart-shrinking - -

Comment: Upon further analysis I have found the error happens only when we are PDF printing with header and footer. Currently our header and footer also contain images.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with `wkhtmltopdf-0.12.4` and is fixed in `0.12.5`.

https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2510